# How to Save an Input table in Mining Model Prediction tab in SSAS

Tags: ssas, data-mining, modeling, decision-tree

I am using SSAS (Visual Studio 2010) to create a Decision Tree model. After the model has been created I can go to the Mining Model Prediction tab to "score" another data set against the model.

However, if I close the Mining Structure (or the solution) and open it again the "scoring" data set that I have connected to the model is gone and I have to repeat all the mapping again.

Is there is a way to save not only the Mining Structure but also the scoring data set?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to a SQL database, then make a linked server to your SSAS OLAP server, then try this...

```
insert into myTempResults (columns....)

select columns.... from OPENQUERY(SSAS_OLAP_LINKED_SERVER, 'your mdx query').
```

you probably need to use FLATTENED in the expression that joins to the mining model

also take a look here for more info..

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/92d22b85-0c8c-4db2-a931-5188f7ad90dc/push-mdx-query-result-to-sql-table-with-in-caption-of-members?forum=sqlanalysisservices